# Reverse words in a string without affecting space

Tags: c++, strings

I came across a problem that needs to reverse each word in a string without affecting space in it. For example, if a string has two spaces between the word, the answer needs to have space between two words. These are example test cases, I have been given
**/This is a sentence/**
**/ This  is a Sentence /**
My approach is:

```
string oreverse(string s){
    for(int i=0,n=s.size();i<n/2;++i)
        swap(s[i],s[n-i-1]);
    return s;
}
string reverseWords(string s) {
    string re;
    for(auto i=0;i<s.size();){
        if(s[i]!=' '||s[i]=='/0'){
            int _t = s.find_first_of(' ',i);
            re+=oreverse(s.substr(i,_t-i));
            i=_t;
        }else{
            re+=s[i];
            i++;
        }
    }
    return re;
}
```

I like to know, is there any further optimisation can be done or any other approaches with increased efficiency.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Could you please provide an example main and provide all of the includes? Also, did you test this? The compiler should complain about `'/0'`, as it should be `'\0'`.

Comment: It's an online compiler and it haven't shown me the error I have done. Maybe. something wrong with the compiler.

Comment: @Aswin we need some more context (and example of the expected input/output). About context: which locales you need to support? To reverse an ASCII7 string is trivial, to reverse a string with modifiers, Unicode surrogate pairs, multi-byte UTF8 encoded code-points and other Unicode sequences (and, in general, grapheme clusters) is more complex. To handle tailored grapheme clusters is MORE complex. To reverse a string according to character directionality (to support RTL language) is MUCH MUCH more complex. To do it in a performance critical snippet is even worse.

Comment: In short: your C++ _code_ might be reviewed (someone already did) but to be fundamentally broken may be your algorithm...

Comment: @Aswin, please do not update code after receiving an answer, as it invalidates the answer. Please read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 3):

## Use compiler warnings

You should always enable compilers warning in c++. For your code, clang & g++ gives the following warnings ([live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/qswjiVNP5oPyGqzq)):

```
prog.cc:14:29: warning: multi-character character constant [-Wmultichar]
        if(s[i]!=' '||s[i]=='/0'){
                            ^
prog.cc:13:19: warning: comparison of integers of different signs: 'int' and '...' (aka 'unsigned long') [-Wsign-compare]
    for(auto i=0;i<s.size();){
                 ~^~~~~~~~~
prog.cc:14:27: warning: result of comparison of constant 12080 with expression of type '...' (aka 'char') is always false [-Wtautological-constant-out-of-range-compare]
        if(s[i]!=' '||s[i]=='/0'){
                      ~~~~^ ~~~~
```

The ones about `s[i]=='/0'` are especially concerning. You probably meant `s[i]=='\0'`. I don't know if you want to handle other possible separators of a string (like tabs, line feeds). If it's the case, you should have a look at [std::isspace](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isspace) or [std::isblank](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isblank).

The one about the `for` suggests that the type `int` (deduced for `auto`) might not be the most suited as a string/vector index. According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/409396), the most portable index type to use would be `std::string::size_type`.

## Avoid std::string copy

Your code is performing a lot of string construction / copy / concatenation. They all can cause memory allocation/deallocation, which can be quite costly compared to the rest of your code. You should be able to avoid most of them.

### Output: generate the result directly in a single std::string

- You know exactly the size of the output string `re` (same size as input). You can preallocate it with [std::string::reserve](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/reserve).
- Pass a reference to `re` to `void oreverse(std::string& output,/*InputType*/ input)`, and directly [push_back](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/push_back) the characters of the input in reverse order.

### Input: work directly on the input string

- pass your input string by (const) references in both functions: `const std::string&`.
- avoid std::string::substr:

  - C++17: you can use [std::string_view](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view) instead of std::string. It's substr method won't do any copy.
  - Pre-C++17: pass iterators to the input string to `oreverse`. Or a (const) reference to the input string, with start/end indices.

## Use "static" for global functions when applicable

Declaring a global function as "static" indicates to your compiler that your function is used only in the current translation unit (current *.cpp file). The compiler can use this information to do better inlining decisions (see for example gcc/g++: [-finline-functions-called-once option](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html)).

Comment: Thanks @vincent-saulue-laborde. I'll consider your points and learn through it.

Answer (score 3):

Well, Vincent covered almost everything as I was writing up alternative implementation... I'll just cover the rest then:

### Do not make unqualified calls

Unqualified call is a non-member function call which doesn't have `::` in front of to-be-called function name. Example:

```
std::sort(numbers.begin(), numbers.end()); //qualified
sort(numbers.begin(), numbers.end()); //unqualified
```

The latter can do something [abysmally evil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49748423/how-does-this-template-type-deduction-and-overload-resolution-work). If you don't know what ADL is, do not make unqualified calls.

### Use iterators, possibly templated

Templates are not always a good thing, but using iterators is mostly a good thing. If one is tired of writing `begin()/end()` pair, one can just provide adapter interface for it.

---

### Alternative implementation

When creating non-trivial algorithm, it is better to get a pen and something to write on. One can observe that there are only two parts to this algorithm:

1) Copy into result until non-space is found

2) Anchor on current position, find first space occurrence from anchor, then reverse copy into the result

The whole algorithm then looks like this:

```
while didn't reach end:
    execute 1)
    if reached end, break
    execute 2)
```

One can extract 1) and 2) into their own functions, but since they're trivial I didn't do so.

---

### Code

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

namespace rev {
    using iterator = std::string::const_iterator;

    std::string reverse_words(iterator first, iterator last) {
        std::string reversed_words(std::distance(first, last), '\0');
        auto d_first = reversed_words.begin();

        while (first != last) {
            while (first != last and *first ==' ')
                *d_first++ = *first++;
            if (first == last) break;

            auto word_anchor = first;
            while (first != last and *first != ' ')
                ++first;

            std::reverse_copy(word_anchor, first, d_first);
            d_first += std::distance(word_anchor, first);
        }
        return reversed_words;
    }
}

int main() {
    std::string words = "This is a bunch of words";
    auto reversed = rev::reverse_words(words.begin(), words.end());

    std::cout << reversed << '\n';
}
```

[Demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/gBh2toDs9a9s9f1q).